# Google Safe Browsing V4 - Unable to send request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, safe-browsing

I have been working on google safe browsing API - I am sure I am doing everything correct but I get the error when I try to connect to the API

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I have correct nuGet package installed

My code is the following

```
try
{
    //cient_info
    Google.Apis.Safebrowsing.v4.Data.ClientInfo client = new Google.Apis.Safebrowsing.v4.Data.ClientInfo();
    client.ClientId = "testapp";
    client.ClientVersion = "1";

    //thread_info
    Google.Apis.Safebrowsing.v4.Data.ThreatInfo threadInfo = new Google.Apis.Safebrowsing.v4.Data.ThreatInfo();
    threadInfo.ThreatTypes.Add("MALWARE");
    threadInfo.ThreatTypes.Add("SOCIAL_ENGINEERING");
    threadInfo.PlatformTypes.Add("WINDOWS");
    threadInfo.ThreatEntryTypes.Add("URL");

    //url to check
    Google.Apis.Safebrowsing.v4.Data.ThreatEntry ITEM = new Google.Apis.Safebrowsing.v4.Data.ThreatEntry();
    ITEM.Url = "http://www.google.com.au/";
    threadInfo.ThreatEntries.Add(ITEM);

    //API Call
    var googleClient = new WebClient();
    var response = googleClient.DownloadString("https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/" + client + threadInfo + "&key=myapikey");
    var releases = JObject.Parse(response);
    return releases.ToString();
}
catch (Exception X)
{
    var Error = X.Message;
    return Error.ToString();
}
```

I think i am messing up at `var response = googleClient.DownloadString` but I am not sure what is the correct call method for this.

Does anyone have any idea?

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure you added your API key?

Answer (score 1):

I used `ThreatMatches.Find()` and it worked.

```
ThreatMatchesResource.FindRequest request = service.ThreatMatches.Find(
new FindThreatMatchesRequest{Client = client, ThreatInfo = threatInfo});

FindThreatMatchesResponse execute = await request.ExecuteAsync();

var releases = execute.ToString();
```

Comment: To be honest I don't remember how I fixed it... Cheers

Comment: The only important thing is that it is fixed:D

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your api key in

```
googleClient.DownloadString("https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/" + client + threadInfo + "&key=myapikey");
```